# Toggle a Boolean in a Binding object doesn't update UI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

Hello i have an issue with the refresh of my view when i toggle a boolean.
Here is the code

```
class MyItem: Identifiable {
   @Published var isActive: Bool
}

struct myView: View {
   @Binding var item: MyItem
   var body: some View {
      HStack {
         Toggle("", isOn: $item.isActive)
         Spacer()
         TextField("", text: item.isActive ? $text : .constant("")) { isFocused in
             guard !isFocused && text.count == 0 else { return }
             item.isActive.toggle
         }
            .background(item.isActive ? Color.white : Color.clear)
      }
   }
}
```

when i lose my focus and run `item.isActive.toggle` it change correctly his value, but my `Toggle` and my `TextField` doesn't update their UI (the Toggle is still active and the background of the TextField is still white)

Any idea of what i am missing ?

Comment: In context of SwiftUI Published works only in ObservableObject which is wrapped in ObservedObject in view. Find some tutorial by key words.

Comment: How do you supply the binding from the superview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Binding` only updates the view when the wrapped value is updated. However, since your wrapped value is a class, not a `struct`, the view would only be updated if you replaced the instance with another one, not if you updated a property of the instance.

You need to make `MyItem` conform to `ObservableObject` and use `@ObservedObject` or `@StateObject` on your view, then it will be updated correctly.

```
class MyItem: ObservableObject {
   @Published var isActive: Bool
}

struct myView: View {
   @ObservedObject private var item: MyItem

   init(item: MyItem) {
       self.item = item
   }

   var body: some View {
      HStack {
         Toggle("", isOn: $item.isActive)
         Spacer()
         TextField("", text: item.isActive ? $text : .constant("")) { isFocused in
             guard !isFocused && text.count == 0 else { return }
             item.isActive.toggle
         }
            .background(item.isActive ? Color.white : Color.clear)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but i have to keep `@Binding private var item: MyItem` because `myView ` is used as an item list which will update his parent's viewModel.
`ForEach($viewModel.items) { $item in
                            MyView(item: $item) }`

Comment: @user3227545 no, you don't. You can get a `Binding` from an `ObservedObject` using the same `$` syntax and everything will work perfectly.

Comment: After some tests in works just fine. On my parent view my array of item is up to date when i check on click on a button. In addition i am looking for a way to catch update of the item in my parent via the array of item. have you an idea for that ?

Comment: @GauthierBeignie you mean you want to update the parent view itself when any item updates? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58996712/4667835) answer explains how to propagate changes from child `ObservableObject`s to their parents.